# shell scripting - after I source a environmental file, the mail command does not work

Tags: shell, ksh

I have two files `test.sh` and `setEnv.sh` under the `/home` folder.

`test.sh` file content is:

```
#!/bin/ksh
source /home/setEnv.sh
mail -s "This is the subject" myemail@test.com <<< 'This is the message'
```

`setEnv.sh` file content is:

```
export envFile=/home/setEnv.sh
export REPORTS_DIR=/home/reports
export REPORT_ARCHIVE_DIR=/home/archive
```

When I run `./test.sh`, the email is not sent, but if I put the line:

```
mail -s "This is the subject" myemail@test.com <<< 'This is the message'
```

Before this line:

```
source /home/setEnv.sh
```

It works fine.

And if I don't source the `setEnv.sh` file and instead define all the variable in the same file, then the email functionality works too.

Only if I use the mail command after `source`, it does not work. Not sure how to get this working.

Comment: Did you mean to surround the entire `mail` command in double quotes (`"`) the second time? Are any errors reported after you run `test.sh`?

Comment: I was just referring to the line. I did not mean to have double quotes.          When I run It returns something like this -   'Sendmail arguments: "send-mail" "-i" "--" "myemail@test.com"'

Comment: Are you sending mail to an actual email address that you can check to see if the email is actually sent? I believe the problem is that your `mail` isn't configured correctly.

Comment: I am sending it to the  actual email address. As i said if i put the 'mail' command before sourcing the environment file. It works fine, i do get a mail.

Comment: And you included all of the contents of both files in your question? I'm not seeing anything that would make your script not work. Unless it has something to do with permissions, which I'm unsure of.

Comment: Try setting each one of those environment variables individually and see which one of them, if any of them, stops the mail from working. You can do this in your normal interactive shell most likely. If, after doing that, none of them stop the mail singly try pairs. Either you'll find which is the problem (in which case you can try to narrow down why) or you'll find that they aren't the problem (and hopefully have gotten a hint as to what else might be going on in the process).

Comment: I just tried as per Etan's comment, the issue was with this environmental variable.                                                         export debug=echo.                                                      When I commented this line, it worked. Johnny I did not mention about this line, never thought this would cause problem. Thank you so much Etan Reisner and Johny Henly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "source" keyword in the ksh, so it is anybodies guess what that "source" command in fact does. If you don't have an alias definition or something such somewhere else it is definitely not "dot-executing" the file "/home/setEnv.sh".

Try:

```
#!/bin/ksh
. /home/setEnv.sh
mail -s "This is the subject" myemail@test.com <<< 'This is the message'
```

Comment: Ksh93, pdksh and mksh have a predefined `alias source='command .'` (or a minor variation of that). Even if the question was about an older version of ksh without this alias, there's no `set -e` in the script, so if `source` was undefined or was an external command, the `mail` command would still be executed.

Comment: ksh93 - at least in AIX, i can't test it anywhere else right now - has no such thing as a "predefined `alias source='command .'`":

 The ksh88 ("ksh" on the systems i work with, ksh93 would be "ksh93") also doewsn't have that. mksh and pdksh are hardly ksh-compatible at all and there is no indication that thread o/p meant anything else than a real ksh.